# Filebeat 'add fields in module' and 'fields_under_root' not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

This is my AWS module setting in K8S

```
filebeat.modules:
  - module: aws
    cloudtrail:
      enabled: true
      var.queue_url: 
      input:
        fields:
          cloud.service.name: cloudtrail
          cloud.service.type: cloudtrail
        fields_under_root: true
```

But since I view the log in the Kibana

```
{
  "_index": ".log-aws-1",
  "fields": {
     "fields.cloud.service.name": [
         "cloudtrail"
     ],
     ...
  }
}
```

This is issues

- not work adding 'cloud.service.type' field.
  I changed 'input' to 'inputs', but not work.
- not work 'fields_under_root', it seems 'fields.fields.cloud.service.name'

What should I do to apply two cases?

Comment: You're showing the [`fields` which is a bit different](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#search-fields-param), but what do you see [in the `_source`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering) when looking in Kibana in the document details?

Comment: there is no _source fields in kibana data. How can I find that field' value?

Comment: Of course there is, just open the document in the Discover view and then select the "Source" tab